# Как мне перенести проект без проблем в VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Есть проект, который делал в Pycharm. Возникла необходимость продолжать его в VSCode. Как мне его безболезненно перенести?

Comment: Открыть папку проекта в vscode. Все.

Comment: чтоб совсем безболезненно, лучше скопировать этот каталог и там уже резвиться.

Comment: Делаю онлайн-магазин в учебных целях. Я использую в проекте django и js. Когда запускаю проект, то на веб-странице какая-то дичь отображается, вместо картинок и т.д. куски кода по типу "{% load static %}". Хотя в vscode устанавливал расширения питон, джанго. Не очень шарю, вполне возможно, что упустил что-либо

Comment: "вместо картинок и т.д. куски кода по типу "{% load static %}"." - значит вы не запускаете django проект (`python manage.py runserver` в командной строке), а просто открываете html файлы шаблонов в браузере. Это вообще никак не связано с переходом с pycharm в vscode, в pycharm аналогично нужно запускать (ну разве что у вас pro версия, там возможно немного проще)

Comment: спасибо, затупил